# Trying to save a list of image names to Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save the image names which i am getting from the imagepicker to the firestore database

How i declared it

```
List<File> _imageName = [];
```

Stored the name

```
_imageName.add(File(Path.basename(pickedFile.path)));
```

Output of _imageName

> [File: 'image_picker2088970390141772511.jpg', File: 'image_picker4765409869719291061.jpg', File: 'image_picker8815762890677993639.jpg', File: 'image_picker2293914669929574097.jpg']

How i tried to saved it to the firestore

```
"imageUrl": FieldValue.arrayUnion(imageUrl),
```

Error

> E/flutter (30296): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of '_File'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there you cannot save a File type directly to Firestore, you need to save it as a string. for example if you just want the name of the file try extracting it from your path when creating your array,

`imageName.add(File(Path.basename(pickedFile.path)).path.split('/').last)`

or since you already had the path.

`imageName.add(pickedFile.split('/').last)`

Finally if you need to actually save the file and not only the path, than you may need to use firebase storage for that.

You can also create an extension to just use a .name methods on your files. For example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

extension FileExtention on FileSystemEntity{
  String get name {
    return this?.path?.split("/")?.last;
  }
}
```

And then you would do something like this:
`imageName.add(File(Path.basename(pickedFile.path)).name)`

Comment: @zerochill sorry I edited my answer because I initially misread. You know have the correct way to save only the name.

Comment: It was giving a error " The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'. Then i changed "List<File> _imageName = [];" to List _imageName = []; then your code worked . Thanks for helpinggbaccetta.

Comment: You are welcome: Sorry I should have specified to change the List Type from File to String

Comment: gbaccetta is there any way by which i pass the getDownloadUrl() to the_imageName list, because I don't know how to get images with just name,

Comment: For that you should be more specific, maybe asking a new question with more code. In fact it depends what downloadUrl you are talking about. If the image is from a server actually store the url on firestore instead of the last part of the url as I suggested and you will get the whole link... however if the image is on local storage that is more complicated, as local storage can also change... you may want to upload it first to firebase storage... So again it depends on your usecase and setup. Either than that, an url/path is a string as a string as a simple filename

Comment: I am just uplaoding image file to firebase and saving its name to firestore, but now i realized that I have to save the download url which firebase storage gives so i can use it to show images in my app. Yes i also think i should provide more code and ask another question.

Comment: If you already do the upload and save it, it's quite easy, the download_url is returned by the upload function. Just pass it to your imageName array (that you should rename imageUrl), with a toString() at the end, if it's not already a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232914/discussion-between-zerochill-and-gbaccetta).